# Transforming dataset

Tags: r, excel

I have a dataset that looks like below that I want to trasnsform to another format that assign true/false based on whether certain string is present. What's the best way to do it either in Excel or R?
Thanks!

Initial dataset:

```
Row1 A D
Row2 B C
Row3 A C E
```

The format I want:

```
      A B C D E
Row1  1 0 0 1 0
Row2  0 1 1 0 0
Row3  1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Please post your data in `dput` format. Edit the question with the output of `dput(dataset)`. Or is it data in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way with `lapply` and `xtabs`.
I assume that `filename` holds the data file name.

```r
x <- readLines(filename)
x <- strsplit(x, " ")
l <- lapply(x, \(y) {
  values <- y[-1]
  rows <- rep(y[1], length(values))
  data.frame(rows, values)
})
df1 <- do.call(rbind, l)
rm(x, l)

xtabs(~ rows + values, df1)
#>       values
#> rows   A B C D E
#>   Row1 1 0 0 1 0
#>   Row2 0 1 1 0 0
#>   Row3 1 0 1 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @FocusC Right. But my answer uses base R only, reshaping to wide format with `xtabs`.

Comment: Sorry, the previous mesage was ment for the other answer. I've also tried yours but RStudio says unexpected token \ on the line l <- lapply(x, \(y) {

Comment: @FocusC `\(y)` is the new way of creating anonymous functions introduced in R 4.1, if it gives an error, use `function(y)` instead. Time to update R?